# Library stlport_shared not found in Titanium Application

Tags: android, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want create a Titanium module, therefore I have a class that extends KrollModule and its method:

```
@Kroll.method
public void example()
{   
    Activity activity = this.getActivity();
    String filesDir = activity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

When I try to use this module in my application in this way:

```
var w = require('com.module3');
w.example();
```

I have the follow error:

```
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [30,975] Sending event: exception on       thread: KrollRuntimeThread msg:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library stlport_shared not      found; Titanium 2.1.0,2012/06/28 12:16,6e3cab6
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library stlport_shared not found
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)]   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)]   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.initRuntime(V8Runtime.java:59)
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.doInit(KrollRuntime.java:163)
[ERROR][TiApplication(  286)]   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:101)
```

I search stlport_shared and it is present in C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.1.0.GA\android\native\libs\x86. Can somebody help me to understand the problem?